# what coordinate system is this and how to convert it to longitude latitudes?

Tags: converters, latitude-longitude, arcgis, coordinate-systems

I'm working with a coordinate system but I don't know what type of coordinate system is that.
Here is the part of the data set that I have.in 2nd and 3rd row shows the coordinate system.

Intersection Point Coordinate
                            N (X)                                  E (Y)       
             384030.906                  474784.247 
             384041.740                  474892.294   
             384095.694                  475203.524

These are real coordinates which were used in Sri Lanka and I want to map these coordinates in GIS map.(I'm making an android app to draw path according to the coordinates by using ArcGIS runtime sdk.)I need to find out what type of coordinate system is this and how to convert it in to longitude latitude? plz help me on this.thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This might be in a Kalianpur (Indian Sub-continet) coordinate system with units in meters.

You can open a map and add a country boundary for Sri Lanka, such as this one: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=a842e359856a4365b1ddf8cc34fde079
zoom towards the locale, if known, and choose different coordinate systems under the Layers button > coordinate system.  The choose the general tab and pick different units until the measurements look good.

You can create xy data using the following instructions: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s50000001z000000

A quick and dirty approach is to move your cursor around and create points in a shapefile in an edit session.